# Canvas string click detection

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent

I'm working on a game and for the menus I'm using `Canvas`es to draw the stuff for that menu.

For options and buttons I'm using Graphics on the canvas to draw a string.  How to detect the mouse clicking the string?

options canvas:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class OptionsScreen extends Canvas{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Mouse ms = new Mouse();
private int optionPos = 275;
private int volLev = 100;
private int screenX = 800;
private int screenY = 600;
private JFrame mainWindow;

public OptionsScreen(JFrame f)
{
    mainWindow = f;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setFont(new Font("JI-Pelter", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    g.setColor(Color.lightGray);

    //Draw strings
    //Music and Sound
    g.drawString("Music:", optionPos, 150); g.setColor(Color.yellow); g.drawString("On", optionPos + 100, 150); g.setColor(Color.white); g.drawString("Off", optionPos + 175, 150); g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    g.drawString("Sound:", optionPos, 200); g.setColor(Color.yellow); g.drawString("On", optionPos + 100, 200); g.setColor(Color.white); g.drawString("Off", optionPos + 175, 200); g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    g.drawString("Volume Level:", optionPos, 250); g.setColor(Color.white); g.drawString(volLev + "%", optionPos + 175, 250); g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    //OpenGL Settings
    g.drawString("Advanced OpenGL:", optionPos, 300); g.setColor(Color.white); g.drawString("On", optionPos + 225, 300); g.setColor(Color.yellow); g.drawString("Off", optionPos + 300, 300); g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    //Screen Settings
    g.drawString("Game Resolution:", optionPos, 350); g.setColor(Color.white); g.drawString(screenX + "x" + screenY, optionPos + 200, 350); g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    this.addMouseListener(ms);
}
}

class Mouse implements MouseListener
{
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: Don't mix Swing components (e.g. `JFrame`) with AWT components (e.g. `Canvas`).  *"(Code later)"* (Answers later)

Comment: the paint method is for painting, nothing else. The other way round: listener registration must be done (once only) elsewhere

Comment: why re-invent the wheel? There are components doing all those nitty-gritty details (buttons f.i.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a JLabel for the strings. Then you can add a MouseListener to the label.

Comment: If using a is possible for the OP, this is definitely the easier way to go

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `getStringBounds` method in `FontMetrics` to get the bounds of your string and determine if that rectangle was clicked in.

As Andrew Thomspon mentioned, you should avoid mixing swing (lightweight) and awt (heavyweight) components if you can (though you can do it if needed http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/).

Comment: I vote for yours. getStringBounds() is a much better suggestion.

Comment: ok, I got a `FontMetrics` and have it set to the graphics, how do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply assign a rectangular region to a given menu item, and if a click occurs in a given region then you know its corresponding menu item has been clicked.